# MYSQL Concatenate columns without grouping

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a single table containing country codes, and language ids

```
+------+------+-------------+
|  id  | iso  | language_id |
+------+------+-------------+
|  1   |  US  |      4      |
|  2   |  IE  |      1      |
|  3   |  DE  |      2      |
|  4   |  SG  |      1      |
|  5   |  FR  |      3      |
|  6   |  UK  |      1      |
|  7   |  AT  |      2      |
+------+------+-------------+
```

What I need is a MySQL statement that will return a result set containing EVERY ISO and a concatenated string of ids where the language id matches

So in the example above, I am looking to get

```
+------+------+----------+
|  id  | iso  | id_group |
+------+------+----------+
|  1   |  US  |     4    |
|  2   |  IE  |  2,4,6   |
|  3   |  DE  |   3,7    |
|  4   |  SG  |  2,4,6   |
|  5   |  FR  |     5    |
|  6   |  UK  |  2,4,6   |
|  7   |  AT  |   3,7    |
+------+------+----------+
```

My best attempt so far is shown below and in the sqlfiddle link, but the grouping is excluding some of the ISO's. I need to return every row

```
SELECT iso, language_id, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as id 
FROM countries 
GROUP BY language_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/907618/3

Can this be done with MySQL or will I need to run many statements to get the results?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do the concatenation part in MySQL but, either way, it can be very easily accomplished. It's just a JOIN.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. As I said, this was my best attempt. Thanks

Comment: Your best attempt doesn't have a join. Try with a JOIN. It's almost impossible that you could fail to solve this.

Comment: It may be impossible for you to solve, but mysql is very new to me. I spent nearly two hours just coming up with the statement above. I think it is fair to say I am not going to progress any more on this without help - which is why I came to a forum where you ask for help, not motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return all ID for every language ID:

```
select language_id, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) as id_group
from countries 
group by language_id
```

then you just have to join this query with the countries table:

```
select
  c.id,
  c.iso,
  g.id_group
from
  countries c inner join (
    select language_id, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) as id_group
    from countries 
    group by language_id
  ) g on c.language_id = g.language_id
order by
  c.id
```

Without a subquery you could use a self-join:

```
select
  c.id,
  c.iso,
  group_concat(c1.id order by c1.id) as id_group
from
  countries c inner join countries c1
  on c.language_id = c1.language_id
group by
  c.id,
  c.iso
```

Comment: There's no need for a subquery here. A JOIN will suffice.

Comment: @Strawberry yes it is true, but I think a subquery is clearer and easier to understand

Comment: Perhaps we can agree to disagree.

Comment: In the absence of any useful examples with joins, I will accept this answer. It does exactly what I need. Thanks @fthiella